# How to record video with front camera without mirror effect in android 6.0

Tags: android

I want to record video with the front camera using **SurfaceView** and **MediaRecorder** but the video is flipped horizontally.

How do I record original video in the same orientation as when previewed on **SurfaceView**

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot achieve this with MediaRecorder. You can swap the pixels and use MediaCodec to achieve this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249032/192373