# Camera application flips the recorded video

Tags: android, video, android-camerax

I am developing an Android application for video camera, I am using the new CameraX Api for my application. This api is really easy to implement and everything working fine in my app, but the problem is in my front camera recording. If i open the front camera it shows me mirror image, this is fine and normal for every camera view but if i record video using my front facing camera then the recorded video flips horizontally. How can i prevent from that video fliping? I want record video just like Snapchat or Instagram

```
private void startCamera() {

    CameraX.unbindAll();

    Rational aspectRatio = new Rational (textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
    Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen


    PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setLensFacing(lensFacing).setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
    final Preview preview  = new Preview(pConfig);

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
            new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                //to update the surface texture we  have to destroy it first then re-add it
                @Override
                public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(textureView);
                    parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                    textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                    updateTransform();
                }
            });

    ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setLensFacing(lensFacing).setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

    VideoCaptureConfig videoCaptureConfig = new VideoCaptureConfig.Builder().setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            .setAudioRecordSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
    final VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(videoCaptureConfig);

    findViewById(R.id.vidStart).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Pic captured at " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Pic capture failed : " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null){
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            videoCapture.startRecording(file, new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Vid captured at " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(VideoCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.vidStop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoCapture.stopRecording();
        }
    });

    //bind to lifecycle:
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, videoCapture);
}
```

Comment: can you share your capture code?

Comment: Yes I will edit the Question and add the code

Comment: ?? where is the code?

Comment: I have added the camera code, kindly help me on this

Comment: find out that how can set orientation in AndroidX. I did in Android 2 Camera , not in AndroidX Camera

Comment: Its not about orientation dude, its about video screen flipping

Comment: dude,  i  fixed my flip or you can say invers issue with front lens camera with orientation or it is you can call rotation.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/android-camerax-preview-analyze-capture-1b3f403a9395 follow this tutorial may ne you will get your solution.

Comment: The tutorial is about image capturing, I need solution for my video capturing

Answer (score 0):

The flipped output is intended. In most devices, the confusing part is in preview session than recording.

In preview with the front camera, the mirror-like preview is for easy use of the front camera to users.

You need to read this SO answer for deep understanding.
[how-to-make-video-captured-by-front-camera-not-being-inverse-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197703/how-to-make-video-captured-by-front-camera-not-being-inverse-android)